# Ubuntu 14.04 totem video player show big play/pause icon on screen

Tags: unity, video, icons, 14.04, totem

After I updated my desktop to 14.04 totem or unity default video player show it's play/pause icon very big on the screen, and there is nothing in preferences that i can change it.

any suggestions ? [image]

Comment: This is very strange! Have you tried `apt-get install --reinstall totem`? Or install `unity-tweak-tool` and try a different icon theme.

Comment: Thank you It hasn't occurred to me to do the reinstall. It solved.

Comment: I've added that as an answer below; please feel free to accept this as the right answer.

Comment: Re-installing does NOT fix it - help?

Comment: It's been filed as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1309605

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: After a while it comes back and it do not get fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something messed up with your icon set for `totem`.
Just reinstall it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall totem
```

Comment: I tried the same solution but it didn't work. I still get huge icons

Comment: try auto remove then install it again and see if it's ok!

Comment: @ComputerJy Worked for me. Try uninstalling totem with `sudo apt-get purge totem; sudo apt-get autoremove`, then install again with `sudo apt-get install totem`.

Comment: it works for me but only for some time and problem still appear again. Is there some better solution?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Patch code below to totem3.10.1, will fix this annoying problem.

**It may cause other display problems as i haven't run a full test**

have fun!

```
--- totem-3.10.1/src/totem-object.c 2013-09-29 20:18:43.000000000 +0800
+++ totem-3.10.1-myversion/src/totem-object.c   2014-10-08 21:59:52.266918845 +0800
@@ -3356,6 +3356,7 @@
            icon_name = totem_get_rtl_icon_name ("media-playback-start");
        else
            icon_name = "media-playback-pause-symbolic";
+       icon_name = NULL;
        totem_fullscreen_show_popups_or_osd (totem->fs, icon_name, FALSE);
        totem_action_play_pause (totem);
        return TRUE;
@@ -3692,6 +3693,7 @@
        retval = FALSE;
    }

+   icon_name = NULL;
    if (icon_name != NULL)
        totem_fullscreen_show_popups_or_osd (totem->fs,
                             icon_name,
```