# Totem displayed huge icons?

Tags: 14.10, totem

why totem shows huge icons in ubuntu 14.10 as the screenshot ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 totem video player show big play/pause icon on screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453145/ubuntu-14-04-totem-video-player-show-big-play-pause-icon-on-screen)

Comment: the answer doesn't resolve my problem